# Getting the product

Tags: java, product

I'm working on beginner level java programming exercises and one I'm stuck on asks to:

*"Write a program called Product1ToN to compute the product of integers 1 to 10 (i.e., 1×2×3×...×10). Try computing the product from 1 to 11, 1 to 12, 1 to 13 and 1 to 14. Write down the product obtained and explain the results.
Hints: Declares an int variable called product (to accumulate the product) and initialize to 1."*

---

What I've done so far is:

```
 public static void Product1ToN() {

    int product;

    for(int number = 1; number <= 10; number++){
        product = number*number;
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```

How can I write it to get the product of ints?

Comment: start with `int product = 1;`, inside the loop use `product *= number`, which is equivalent to `product = product*number`

Answer (score 4):

At each iteration you want to multiply the current product by the current number:

```
int product = 1;
for(int number = 1; number <= maxNum; number++){
    product *= number;

}
System.out.println(product);
```

Comment: Ideally, the method should take the highest number you multiply by as an explicit parameter and product *= number is a more concise way to write product = number*product.

Comment: @La-comadreja Updated as requested.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Product1ToN(int N) {
    int product = 1;
    for (int number = 2; number <= N; number++) product *= number;
    System.out.println(product);
}
```

Comment: Customarily, the names of Java methods would begin with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int x,Snum,Lnum;
        int product = 1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter starting point number");
        Snum = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Ending point number");
        Lnum = sc.nextInt();
        for (x=Snum; x<=Lnum; x++)
        {
            product *= x;           
        }
        System.out.println("product of numbers = "+product);
    }
}
```